# Get voltage and current noise P-P values for 0.1 to 10 Hz from integrating the curve in the datasheet and comparing the results to the datasheets valu

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise, theory

Usually from OpAmps datasheets, you can get the RTI noise values for both current, and voltage noises exact RMS values for 0.1 Hz to 10 Hz. For a wider frequency range the noise density curve is flat, they usually give you the value for 1kHz. I include an example from the [AD8428](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad8428.pdf) device datasheet:

[image]

They also include a voltage and current noise density curve vs frequency:
[image]

This curve you can describe with the function of

$$ e_n(f) = \frac{1}{f}+e_{n,BB} $$

where E<sub>n</sub>(f) is the noise density, f is the frequency, and e<sub>n, BB</sub> is the broadband noise. Integrating this curve for various frequency ranges you can get a noise there.

### Assumption

My assumption is if you integrate it in the range from 0.1 to 10 Hz and convert it to a p-p value you should get back almost the same value that what you have in the datasheet. Namely 40 nV <sub>p-p</sub> for the voltage and 150 pA <sub>p-p</sub> for the current:

- Integrating from F<sub>L</sub> to F<sub>H</sub>.:

$$ \sqrt{\int_{F_L}^{F_H} {(\frac{1}{f} + e_{n,BB})^2} \,df}\ = \sqrt{\frac {-1}{2(F_H-F_L)} + 2e_{n,BB}[ln(F_H)-ln(F_L)] + e_{n,BB}^2(F_H-F_L)}$$

- Substituting values from voltage noise:
  F<sub>L</sub> = 0.1 Hz,   F<sub>H</sub> = 10 Hz,   e<sub>n,BB</sub> = 1.3 nV/√Hz
  $$ \sqrt{\frac {-1}{2(10-0.1)} + 2*1.3[ln(10)-ln(0.1)] + 1.3^2(10-0.1)} = 5.352 nV_{RMS}$$
  You need to multiply by 6.6 to get the p-p value: 5.35 * 6.6 = **35.329 nV<sub>P-P</sub>**
  This value is close to the datasheets 40 nV<sub>P-P</sub>.
- Substituting values for current noise:
  F<sub>L</sub> = 0.1 Hz,   F<sub>H</sub> = 10 Hz,   e<sub>n,BB</sub> = 1.5 pA/√Hz
  $$ \sqrt{\frac {-1}{2(10-0.1)} + 2*1.5[ln(10)-ln(0.1)] + 1.5^2(10-0.1)} = 6.003 pA_{RMS}$$
  Multiplying by 6.6: 6.003 * 6.6 = **39.621 pA<sub>P-P</sub>**
  ***This value does not correspond to the expected 150 pA<sub>P-P</sub>!!!***

Are there other factors causing noise at low frequencies which is not counted in this noise spectral density curve? Or I did some errors in calculations or assumptions?

Comment: There's usually an scaling factor involved with the 1/f term.

Comment: Does the equation you are integrating give you the points shown on the graph? Eg. at 1Hz does it give you almost 15pA/RtHz?

Comment: You might benefit from Art Kay's App note (Texas Instruments): https://www.ti.com/lit/ml/slyy061/slyy061.pdf?ts=1670263629223&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F